# Why JavaScript Statement "ga = ga || []" Works?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Below javascript statements will cause error, if **ga** is not declared.

```
if (ga)
{
   alert(ga);
}
```

The error is:

```
ga is not defined
```

It looks undeclared variable cannot be recognized in bool expression. So, why below statement works?

```
var ga = ga || [];
```

To me, the ga is treated as bool value before "||". If it is false, expression after "||" is assigned to final ga.

Comment: Did you mean `var ga = ga || []` because `ga = ga || [];` errors out too (as S.Mark pointed out).

Comment: I thought it was ga = ga || oh.la = la; want(yourBadRomance);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: You need to use `var ga;` first or `var ga = ga || [];`, because its declare ga first and assign values into it.

You could try this

```
var x = 1, y = x + 1;
alert([x,y]) // 1,2
```

You may notice, when y is declare, x is already declared and already assigned 1 to it.

So, in your case, when `ga || []` assigns, ga is already declared and its valid variable.

Comment: yes, because, when you use `var` its declare first and assignment happen later on.

Comment: getting 2 downvotes ..., so could somebody please point out my answer is wrong? So I could correct it.

Answer (score 4):

null or defined are falsey values in javascript (implicitly evaluates to false.) the || operator returns the first value that does not evaluate to false.

```
var x = 0 || "" || null || "hello" || false; // x equals "hello"
```

On the other hand the && operator will return the first falsey value or the last value.

```
var y = "a string" && {"attr":"an object"} && false && ["array"]; 
// y equals false

var z = "a string" && {"attr":"an object"} && ["array"]; 
// z equals ["array"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in the case with 'var' because the variable-stop in the scope resolution is created. **Without the 'var' you just run off looking through the scope chains and you get told**. If you *really want* to use a global variable:

```
// This is fine because assignment always sets a property value
// in this case (no 'var ga') it's the same as window.ga = window.ga || []
ga = window.ga || []
```

Or:

```
// Once again, only the lookup is affected with "running off"
// the lookup chain. It's not that the variable has no value --
// the problem is there IS NO VARIABLE.
if (!window.ga) {
  ga = []
}
```

Or even this:

```
// First line is the same as window.ga = window.ga,
// but now the property ga is guaranteed to exist on the window object --
// the VALUE of the property may (still) be undefined
ga = window.ga
ga = ga || []
```

Note that in both these cases I explicitly invoked `ga` as a property of the `window` (global) object.

You can read about the details here: [Identifier Resolution, Execution Contexts and Scope Chains](http://jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html#clIRExSc).

The *placement* of var within a scope does not matter. All of the following are the same:

```
var ga
ga = ga || []

var ga = ga || []

ga = ga || []
var ga
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a less weird-looking option:

```
if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') 
{
   alert(ga);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second statement ga is checked if it is defined and if true, is assigned to itself. Otherwise it's assigned an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting b to be an array, 
probably you want to use an array method on b
or read an index value from it.

```
var b= s.match(/\d+/) || [];
return b[0];
```

this returns the matched text or undefined-

without the empty array assignmentment, the second line would throw an error if there was no match.